# Populate and lock input form field in JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form. I fetch an input field which I populate and then I'd like to set the field to readonly.

Field is defined as:

```
<label>MyId:</label> <input type="text" name="my_id" id="my_id"><br>
```

Then in my Javascript code I do:

```
var row = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
$('#myForm input[name=my_id]').val(row.my_id);
```

However, I'm not sure how to set the field to readonly after I've set the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method to update the property of an element.

```
$('#myForm input[name=my_id]').val(row.my_id).prop('readonly', true);
```

---

Or use [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method to add the attribute.

```
$('#myForm input[name=my_id]').val(row.my_id).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
```

Comment: Thanks I was searching for attr() method or similar but it's called prop().

Comment: @s5s : you can use `attr()` method as well

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following:

```
$('#myForm input[name=my_id]').prop('readonly', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace `$('#myForm input[name=my_id]').val(row.my_id);` with:

```
$('#myForm input[name=my_id]').val(row.my_id).prop('readonly', true);
```